# Change configurable products to simple products

Tags: magento-1.8

I am definitely new to Magento and looking for the way to change the configurable products to simple product. I have 62 Configurable products and each has 3 Associated products by weight 250gms, 500gms, and 1kg now i am trying to change all products to simple. is there any easy way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi Ask4Tec and welcome to magento.stackexchange! What do you intend to do? I mean, you have a configurable with three different attribute values. What should happen with the simples? What attribute value do you want your new simple to have? I would recommend to delete the configurable and just use the three simples, as they already configured correctly? Maybe except the descriptions and pictures...

No, to be honest, the structure between a configurable and a simple product are a little bit different, so I think this is no good idea.

What you can try is:

Load the configurable, set the `$product->setTypeId('simple')`, set the attribute value and then `$product->save()`. But there will remain lots of dead data in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This solution makes visible all the associate products of configurable products in front-end and then deletes the configurable products.

```
// Get the configurable product collection.
    $collectionConfigurable = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                                ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));
    try {
    foreach ( $collectionConfigurable as $parent ) {
        // Get all the children
        $conf = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/product_type_configurable' )->setProduct ( $parent );
        $col = $conf->getUsedProductCollection ()->addAttributeToSelect ( '*' )->addFilterByRequiredOptions ();
        foreach ( $col as $child ) {
            // Set child product visible in frontend.
            $child->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)->save();
        }
        // Remove the parent product.
        $parent->delete();break;
    }
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
```